# Send an email at 14 days before birthday

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I want to send a happy birthday email at D-14 in Marketing Cloud

My problem is that  I find the right clients well but I also find clients whose with a birthday date shifted by a day compared to what I want.

I created my automation the June 16th so I should have clients whose birthday is June 30th. But when I look my DE I can see clients whose birthday is June 29th.

Is it due to leap years?

In my query I used:

```
WHERE DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, CTS.Birthdate) = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,(getUTCDate()+14))
```

How I can have just customers whose their birthday is in 14 days?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that I've used in the past:

```
select
  x.emailaddress
, x.Birthday
, x.age
, x.nextBirthDay
from (

    select
      a.emailaddress
    , a.Birthday
    , datediff(year,a.Birthday, getDate()) as Age
    , case
        when (dateadd(year,datediff(year,a.Birthday,getDate()), a.Birthday) > getDate()) then dateadd(Year,datediff(year,a.Birthday,getDate()), a.Birthday)
        else dateadd(year, datediff(year,a.Birthday,getDate())+1 , a.Birthday)
      end nextBirthDay
    from MasterDE a
    where a.Birthday is not null
) x
where 
datediff(day, getdate(), x.nextBirthDay) = 14
```

The inner query calculates the `Age` and `nextBirthday` for rows in the `MasterDE` data extension.  The outer query chooses only those that are 14 days from today.